# What happened to the Magic Erase tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I select the erase tool, there is no longer drop down to select the Magic Erase tool.  I can not find anywhere on PS CC where the Magic Erase tool is now located?  Hopefully this is not something that the developers deemed unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

It's under the **eraser tool** where it's always been.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The fix for me was to reset the workspace.   Choose Window > Workspace > Essentials (Default).